# implementing camera native module in react native

Tags: java, android, react-native

for some reasons I should not use android.permission.CAMERA in my app.So I can not use react-native-image-picker library.Hence I am implementing a camera native module inorder to take pictures and send them to the server as I am a junior RN developer. my code in the module class for starting the intent is like below :

```
class CameraModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    Activity activity;

    CameraModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Camera";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void onClick() {
           ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();     
            Context context;
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) !=null) {
                activity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            }         
        }

            
    }
```

after this i must write the code for onActivityResult in order to get the final image. but in this level I get the error

**attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int)' on a null object reference**

So any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

This code should works. But a little spoiler if you don't request the permissions it won't work.

```
class CameraModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    Activity activity;

    CameraModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.activity=reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Camera";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void onClick() {
           ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();     
            Context context;
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) !=null) {
                
              activity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            }         
        }

            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I just replaced this part :

```
activity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

with this one :

```
takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(takePictureIntent);
```